# How linear regression algorithm estimates values and draw line

Tags: linear-programming, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am learning Machine Learning. and going through some videos. In that one slide came which I am not able to understand (Attached below). This is related to Linear Regression.

[image: img]

In second image, it starts line from 0's place as value of theta0 is 0. but value of theta1 is 0.5, then why he kept points at (2,1) and (1,2)?

Based on given formula, how this line is going up and how it estimates points/value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h_\theta(x)=\theta_0+\theta_1 x$, and $\theta_0 = 0$ and $\theta_1 = \frac 1 2$, then simple substitution shows that $h_\theta(2) = 0 + \left(\frac 1 2\right)(2) = 1$, so $(2,1)\in h_\theta$.

(I don't think the mark at $(1, 2)$ is meant to be a point, possibly this was just the lecturer's way of drawing the viewer's attention to $h(x)$.)

To answer your question, the line is "going up" because it has a positive gradient (and has a zero intercept because $\theta_0=0$) and is used to estimate values by simple substitution.

Note that these slides are not saying anything about how good a particular model is at producing an estimate, only about how estimates are produced given the model coefficients $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$. The *next* step would be to choose suitable values for $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ that *would* produce good estimates (for example, by minimising some predetermined cost function based on the parameters and the points that are supposed to be modelled).

Comment: Why he assumed value of x as 2 only, and not any other number?

Comment: Did he took random numbers for each test. (for first image 0, second image took 1, and for third one took 3)?

Comment: He's just giving examples of functions with different parameters. (Is this Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course?) Think of it as a function that takes in two parameters $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ and returns a *linear function*, which in turn takes in one argument ($x$) and returns an estimate ($h$). The goal (later on) is to figure out which values of $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ will return the linear function that produces the best (by some measure) predictions.